# Store user video progress every 30 sec Plyr.js

Tags: javascript, plyr

I am trying to get a current video progress value every 5 seconds so I can then make a post to the DB to store it againt User video progress table using JS and Plyr.js API but clearly doing something wrong. My code:

```
player.on('timeupdate', () => {
        const currentTime = document.getElementById('current-time');
        currentTime.innerText = player.currentTime;
        let intervalId = setInterval( () => {
          console.log(`Submitted timestamp to DB every 5 sec`)
        }, 5000);
        if (intervalId) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        //console.log(player.currentTime);
      });
```

The code above does not fire console.log at all. If I remove clearInterval() the console.log gets fired after 5 sec but then repeats every second or so, not after 5 sec.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution after trawling the Plyr docs, listening to play is an option:

```
player.on('play', () => {
        setInterval( function() {
          // POST current time and state to the server
          console.log(player.currentTime);
          const currentTime = document.getElementById('current-time');
          currentTime.innerText = player.currentTime;
        }, 3000);
        //console.log(player.currentTime);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using lodash throttle and the "timeupdate" event.

I prefer this method rather than using setInterval + "play" event, because the "timeupdate" event will be synchronized with the video playback and has more granular playback data.

```
const player = new Plyr(video, defaultOptions);

const handleTimeUpdate = throttle(async (event) => {
   await storeVideoProgress(player.currentTime)
}, 15000);

player.on("timeupdate", handleTimeUpdate);
```